# python: how to pass parameters to application in eclipse without using command prompt

Tags: python, django

I am doing project on django, and every time we have to run project we have to give commands in command prompt. Can we pass arguments to manage.py in eclipse(IDE) itself or at the runconfig.

Please throw some light on this.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a "Run Configuration" in Eclipse to invoke `manage.py`. There is an "Arguments" tab that allows you to provide command line arguments.